# Jquery-Unobtrusive-Ajax Not Finding data-ajax-update

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I have the following link in my MVC Core project:

```
<a asp-action="ArtictleDetailsById" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-area="Global" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="ArticleDetails" class="btn btn-default">View Details</a>
```

which is sending and retrieving data as expected but it is not updating the destination element. More specifically when trying to debug, the following gets evaluated and skipped (from jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js):

```
 $(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-update")).each(function (i, update) {
        var top;

        switch (mode) {
        case "BEFORE":
            top = update.firstChild;
            $("<div />").html(data).contents().each(function () {
                update.insertBefore(this, top);
            });
            break;
        case "AFTER":
            $("<div />").html(data).contents().each(function () {
                update.appendChild(this);
            });
            break;
        case "REPLACE-WITH":
            $(update).replaceWith(data);
            break;
        default:
            $(update).html(data);
            break;
        }
    });
```

But the following code will work (replacing the .each() loop):

```
update = (element.getAttribute("data-ajax-update"));
$('#'+update).html(data);
```

I am wondering if there is a known issue with this, a proper fix, or something I am doing wrong. I saw there were some issues in the past regarding the usage of .live(),  but that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If `ArticleDetails` is the ID of the target dom element, you should add a "#" character in front of it like this:

```
<a asp-action="ArtictleDetailsById" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-area="Global" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#ArticleDetails" class="btn btn-default">View Details</a>
```